# Allow access to PostgreSQL database only through QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, postgis, pyqgis

I created a Python plugin in QGIS that manage the connection to my PostgreSQL database and loading layers in a specific structure, I've created also some personalized widgets to edit attribute tables so that I can control entered data. My problem is that I'm afraid that someone access my database with the username and password provided through other software such as ArcGIS, so how can I make access to my database only allowed through my plugin ?

Comment: The fact that other GIS software, and psql, and pgAdmin (and QGIS, outside your plugin) can access databases is a feature, not a defect.  If you don't want other PostgreSQL clients accessing the database, you have to prevent those clients from existing on the network.

Comment: so there's no tricks I can use ?

Comment: Imagine someone who is always scanning IP addresses of potential PostgreSQL servers). You can just change access password to your database, port number and its IP location from time to time. That's enough I suppose.

Comment: The problem is that they have the right to access my database but I want to limit access to it to be just from my plugin :/